#  in TextArea of OBS

Tags: fonts, obs-studio

Icons are possible to use in OBS-Text-Areas if you use the Font **DeJa Vu Sans** but not all (Example: ☳⚒⚄).

I searching for  without success.

how could i find out if this special (or a other) symbol is possible to use?

Comment: Use a font that actually has the symbol in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I searching for  without success.

All of the available characters are listed in [DejaVuSans.pdf](http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/samples/DejaVuSans.pdf)

(Emoji for Herb) is not listed.

There is a plug-in that supports Emoji:

> - Supported Bit Versions
>   32-bit, 64-bit
> - Source Code URL
>   https://github.com/kkartaltepe/obs-text-pango
> - Minimum OBS Studio Version
>   21.0.0
> - Supported Platforms
>   Windows, Mac OS X, Linux
> - Multi language support on all platforms: full support for Arabic, Hindi, Thai, CJK, Emoji, and more.
> - Packages for Win64 and Mac, dead simple compilation for Linux.
> - Proper Serif/Sans fallback fonts
> - Proper rendering for vertical scripts
> - Proper rendering for RTL scripts
> - Proper outlines (no bars over joined text like in arabic/hindi/emoji)
> - Per line gradients
> - Drop shadows
> - Works with bitmap fonts
> - Automatically detect UTF-8 and UTF-16 text files, or select any other encoding!
> - Force a custom language for Han Unification or other language specific glyphs without changing system language.
> - Multi platform: You get the exact same rendering on all platforms (note: ONLY if you use the same fontconfig and have the same fonts
>   available)

Source: [text-pango: multi-language and emoji | OBS Forums](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/text-pango-multi-language-and-emoji.656/)

Comment: for ubuntu is this the right way to install it ? `sudo apt-get install -y libpango1.0-dev` https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libpango1.0-dev the article is years old

Comment: No idea, sorry.